# Assigning labels to values in chart using Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, chart

with this code I created a land use time series:

```
var imgCol = ee.ImageCollection('users/danielepiccolo/consumo_suolo/CS_ARPAV')
  .select('b1');

var region = ee.FeatureCollection('users/danielepiccolo/Shapefile/Veneto');

var histCol = ee.FeatureCollection(imgCol.map(function(img) {
  var hist = img.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),
    geometry: region,
    scale: 10,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  });
  return ee.Feature(null, hist.get('b1')).copyProperties(img, ['anno']);
})).filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['anno']));


var xProps = histCol.first()
  .propertyNames().filter(ee.Filter.neq('item', 'anno'));

var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byProperty({
  features: histCol,
  xProperties: xProps,
  seriesProperty: 'anno'
}).setOptions({
  title: 'Class histogram per year',
  hAxis: {
    title: 'Class',
  },
  vAxis: {
    title: 'Frequency',
  }
});
print(chart);
```

Now I would like to assign the corresponding labels to the values ​​and sort them following this list:

"1 - Suolo consumato",
"2 - Suolo non consumato",
"11 - Suolo consumato permanente",
"12 - Suolo consumato reversibile",
"111 - Edifici, fabbricati, capannoni",
"112 - Strade asfaltate",
"113 - Sede ferroviaria",
"114 - Aeroporti",
"115 - Porti",
"116 - Altre aree impermeabili/pavimentate non edificate",
"117 - Serre permanenti pavimentate",
"118 - Discariche",
"121 - Strade sterrate",
"122 - Cantieri e altre aree in terra battuta",
"123 - Aree estrattive non rinaturalizzate",
"124 - Cave in falda",
"125 - Campi fotovoltaici a terra",
"126 - Altre coperture artificiali la cui rimozione ripristina le condizioni iniziali del suolo",
"201 - Corpi idrici artificiali",
"202 - Rotonde e svincoli (aree permeabili)",
"203 - Serre non pavimentate",
"204 - Ponti e viadotti su suolo non artificiale"

I thought of putting a `.setSeriesNames` with the list of labels in the chart code but unsuccessful.
I tried to replace values but unsuccessful.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by creating a dictionary from your list and then assign them to your features. Something like:

```
var labels = {
  '1': 'Suolo consumato',
  '2': 'Suolo non consumato',
  ///// ... etc...
};

//// Then use the above dictionary to update the features properties
histCol = histCol.map(function(feature) {
  var properties = feature.toDictionary();
  var newProperties = properties.map(function(value, key) {
    if (key !== 'anno') {
      return labels[key];
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  });
  return ee.Feature(feature.geometry(), newProperties);
});
```

Comment: I try to used your code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/6df282edb4dba3e60eadb956ba15ad0a but there is an error "Line 67: User-defined methods must return a value."